# How to deploy a nodejs app with module.exports on Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am using node js and yarn for my slack bot. Its working fine locally, but I dont know how to deploy that on firebase to let my bot working.
This is my index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
require = require("esm")(module/*, options */);
module.exports = require("./app.js");
```

but to deploy it on firebase I need something like that my index.js:

```
    const app = express();
    exports.widgets = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

but I'm not using express(). So how should I do that? P.S. all my bot logic is in app.js, thats the reason why I `require("./app.js");`

Comment: There's not enough information here to understand what you need to do.  I suggest reviewing the documentation for HTTP triggers to learn how to write and deploy functions. If you're not using express, there are alternatives that you will have to learn.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy with Firebase Hosting: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/deploying. It is pretty easy to use.